# Internal Lerna package import in VSCode on wsl gives typescript error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lerna

I am using WSL on Windows, and typescript in VSCode does not find imported internal modules, as in:

```
import { Something } from "@namespace/package";
```

where namespace/package is in the same mono-repo.
The error message reads:

```
Cannot find module '@namespace/package' or its corresponding type declarations.  ts(2307)
```

This is only a problem in VSCode, as the import works correctly when compiling the typescript and running the app. Colleagues using Unix directly with the same setup do not have this issue.

I have the latest version of VSCode and searched for similar issues, as well as conferred with my colleagues without luck.

Comment: not sure if that helps but make sure that you don't have a casing issue since Unix based are case sensitive but Windows is not. Also make sure that all your packages have a name property defined in your package.json (ie `"name": "@namespace/package"`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have checked and the casing is the same as in the package files.

Comment: What version of vscode are you using?